# requirejs takes over node require() function

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I am trying to load the npm request module, inside of a requirejs define function.

```
define(function () {
console.log("run");
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
    }
})
});
```

When the browser hits the require('request') , it throws this error.

> Uncaught Error: Module name "request" has not been loaded yet for context: _. > Use require([])

From my understanding both nodejs and requirejs define a require() function, so In the tutorial example, 
https://github.com/request/request
I believe when they call require() it is using the nodejs require function, but in my case it thinks require is something different. 
If this is in fact the problem, how can I change the require() function name for either require or node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I install RequireJS and `request` and create a file named `test.js` that contains:

```
var requirejs = require("requirejs");

requirejs("foo");
```

And in the same directory I create a file named `foo.js` that contains your code:

```
define(function () {
console.log("run");
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
    }
})
});
```

And I execute:

```
$ node test.js
```

Then I get `run` on the console plus the body of the page.

I've tried variants:

- Import RequireJS as `require`: `var require = require('requirejs')`
- Use the async form of the call: `requirejs(["foo"])`
- Various mixtures of the above.

I cannot reproduce the behavior you report.

Comment: Hi Louis, thanks for the help. I feel really dum because the questions im about to ask seem super noob, but... im not following you here,
1. When you say "I installed requireJS" are you installing it via node command, or do you mean you are just including it in the library like a regular use case.
I installed request by doing npm install request --save-dev. inside of GitShell command window.
2. When you are going to execute the test.js are you doing so from the powershell and litterally typing in "$ node test.js"?

Comment: I mean I did `npm install requirejs`. I'm running the test from the bash shell. The `$` is an old Unix convention: it represents the shell prompt. You type everything after but not the `$` itself.

Comment: I did an 'npm install requirejs', and ran the test.js, via 'node test.js', and was able to see the console log, and the response of the website in the shell prompt. How do I get this to load like a regular javascript file, so that it fires on page load, and the response is accessible through a normal javascript variable. im confused as to how the shell itself is runnign the test.js as opposed to it loading normally on a webpage.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are asking in this last comment. Everything you described and that I answered loads your code "like a regular javascript file".  Sounds though like you want the code to run in a browser. It's not clear to me what the problem you're having is: you don't know how to serve JavaScript to a browser, how to use RequireJS browser-side, both, neither?

Comment: I am new to node.js so the concept is odd to me, for example you executed test.js by typing in 'node test.js' into the prompt, but how would I get that to run on its own in the server? Like if I clicked a button "run" in a browser window how could I get that to fire the test.js file?  do you simply call the function as you normally would like normal client side javascript, but than it somehow knows that it is a node function. idk im just consfused on the absolute basics i guess.

Comment: SO (Stack Overflow) does not aim to be a tutoring resource. I would suggest using an external resource like a Node tutorial or introduction [like this](http://www.nodebeginner.org/). (I don't know the quality of this resource. It's just what Google gave me.) Then, if there are specific issues you run into, bring them to SO but make sure you've checked that it has not been asked before and that the question is on topic.